# Editing polygon layer and snapping to another layer using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, editing

I'm using ArcMap, and i've got two large polygon layers that are of the same area (Canada).

One layer is made up of 2,500 polygons, the other is 14. when I clip (using one of the 14 layers) I will get slivers of some of the 2,500 polygons along the edges of my clip. this tells me that they arent *exactly* on the same lines.

Is there a way to reshape the 14-polygon layer, using some sort of "snap-to-closest" editing tool? or do I need to go edge by edge along the entire thing to edit the layer?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Integrate - Data Management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) tool?

Comment: or union/clip then eliminate https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005p000000 (advanced license required). Be *very* careful with the integrate tool, it works on the input data and can absolutely ruin your geometries with no hope of undo if you use a tolerance too large, I strongly suggest making a backup of your data before using integrate.

Comment: @mdholl6188 (how do i tag michael?) it looks like Integrate uses a midpoint between the two boundaries, is that correct? One of my layers (the one with 2,500 parts) is the "correct" layer, so Eliminate should work?

also, there are a few boundaries that do NOT share edges with the "correct" layer, will those stay where they should be?